# addition and subractions with jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery for addition & subracting from buttons. what are the changes need to be done in the following query

I have 4 buttons. 50, 100, 500 and 2000. i done upto subraction directly from those 4 buttons

```js
 var setVal = 0;
$(".add").click(function() {
  console.log("clicked", setVal);  
  $(".sub").val(setVal - parseFloat($("#paid").val()));
  setVal = 0;
});

$("form input").click(function() {
  setVal = 0;
  setVal = this.value;
  console.log("setVal--", setVal)
});
```

```html
<div class="cash box"><input type="button"  id="a" value="50" style="height: 30px; width: 40px; margin-top: 25px;">
    <input type="button" id="b" value="100" style="height: 30px; width: 40px">
    <input type="button" id="c" value="500" style="height: 30px; width: 40px">
    <input type="button" id="d" value="2000" style="height: 30px; width: 40px">
</div>


<td><input type="text" name="paid" class="text" id="paid" value="1300"/></td>

 <td> <input type="button" value="Calculate" class="add" id="add"></td>
```

My expected result is when user pays 1500, i have to click 500 three times and then subract the 1300 give change of 200.How to workout on it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help

```js
var setVal = 0;
$(".change").click(function(){
setVal+=Number($(this).val());
})
$(".add").click(function() { 
var x=(parseFloat($("#paid").val())-setVal).toString();
if(x>0)
  $(".sub").text('Take more ' + x);
  else
   $(".sub").text('Give Change ' + x.substr(1,x.length));
  setVal = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cash box"><input type="button" class="change" id="a" value="50" style="height: 30px; width: 40px; margin-top: 25px;">
    <input type="button" id="b" class="change" value="100" style="height: 30px; width: 40px">
    <input type="button" id="c" class="change" value="500" style="height: 30px; width: 40px">
    <input type="button" id="d" class="change" value="2000" style="height: 30px; width: 40px">
</div>


<td><input type="text" name="paid" class="text" id="paid" value="1300"/></td>

 <td> <input type="button" value="Calculate" class="add" id="add"></td>
 <td><p class="sub"></p></td>
```

Comment: hi bro. r u there. i need help in another functionality

Comment: i am creating rows dynamically using this

Comment: oCell = document.createElement("TD");
    oCell.innerHTML = "<div align='center' ><input  type='text' name='vat"+Row+"' id='vat"+Row+"' class='textbox'  size='10' readonly> </div>"; 
     row.appendChild(oCell);

Comment: in that field i am getting the value for 'vat'.   for 1st row, the id becomes vat1 and for send row the id becomes vat2 like that increasing

Comment: now i need to add vat1, vat2,.... and display it in another text field with id  'vat'

Comment: hi ashay, how can i ping u personally??

Comment: how to connect with u

Comment: i sent u request, pls check it